# Json Parsing error in my project

Tags: android, json

Am developing a project in android which gets the data from webservice using json and displaying in a listview.

i parsed the data and while run the app in emulator it force closed.

what I have done wrong? Correction will be appreciated.

Here is my full code

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://example.com/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "Product";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "shop_prdt_id";
    private static final String TAG_CATID="shop_cat_id";
    private static final String TAG_SCATID="shop_scat_id";
    private static final String TAG_PRODCODE="shop_prdt_code";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE="shop_prdt_title";
    private static final String TAG_LISTPRICE = "shop_prdt_listprice";
    private static final String TAG_OURPRICE = "shop_prdt_ourprice";
    private static final String TAG_YOU = "shop_prdt_yousave";
    private static final String TAG_STOCK = "shop_prdt_stock";
    private static final String TAG_WEIGHT = "shop_prdt_weight";
    private static final String TAG_WEIGHTMEASURE = "shop_prdt_weight_measurement";
    private static final String TAG_PRODCOLOR = "shop_prdt_color";
    private static final String TAG_SIZE = "shop_prdt_size";
    private static final String TAG_SPLDESC = "shop_prdt_spl_description";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "shop_prdt_description";
    private static final String TAG_FEATURE="shop_prdt_featured";
    private static final String TAG_SEOTITLE="shop_prdt_seo_title";
    private static final String TAG_SEODESC="shop_prdt_seo_desc";
    private static final String TAG_SEOKEYWORDS="shop_prdt_seo_keywords";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGES="shop_prdt_images";
    private static final String TAG_CLICKS="shop_prdt_clicks";
    private static final String TAG_CREATEDATE="shop_prdt_createdon";
    private static final String TAG_UPDATEDATE="shop_prdt_updatedon";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS="shop_prdt_status";
    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray product = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            product = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

            // looping through All product
            for(int i = 0; i < product.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = product.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String catid = c.getString(TAG_CATID);
                String Subcatid=c.getString(TAG_SCATID);
                String prcode =c.getString(TAG_PRODCODE);
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String listprice =c.getString(TAG_LISTPRICE);
                String ourprice = c.getString(TAG_OURPRICE);
                String you=c.getString(TAG_YOU);
                String stock =c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
                String weight =c.getString(TAG_WEIGHT);
                String weightmes =c.getString(TAG_WEIGHTMEASURE);
                String color =c.getString(TAG_PRODCOLOR);
                String size =c.getString(TAG_SIZE);
                String spldesc =c.getString(TAG_SPLDESC);
                String desc =c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                String feature =c.getString(TAG_FEATURE);
                String seotitle=c.getString(TAG_SEOTITLE);
                String seodesc =c.getString(TAG_SEODESC);
                String seokeywords =c.getString(TAG_SEOKEYWORDS);
                String images =c.getString(TAG_IMAGES);
                String clicks =c.getString(TAG_CLICKS);
                String createdate =c.getString(TAG_CREATEDATE);
                String updatedate =c.getString(TAG_UPDATEDATE);
                String status =c.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_OURPRICE, ourprice);
                map.put(TAG_YOU, you);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_OURPRICE, TAG_YOU }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String ourprice1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String you1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, name1);
                in.putExtra(TAG_OURPRICE, ourprice1);
                in.putExtra(TAG_YOU, you1);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

My json file

```
    {
    "Product": [
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "11",
            "shop_cat_id": "3",
            "shop_scat_id": "0",
            "shop_prdt_code": "06PTPL-01PK",
            "shop_prdt_title": "Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "44",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "40",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "4",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "20",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "17.67",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "3,4,7,8,12,13,14",
            "shop_prdt_size": "3,5,11,13",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales at. Nulla tellus elit, varius non commodo eget, mattis vel eros. In sed ornare nulla.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales at. Nulla tellus elit, varius non commodo eget, mattis vel eros. In sed ornare nulla.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "13",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-29 02:26:08",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "2013-11-17 17:27:37",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "8",
            "shop_cat_id": "2",
            "shop_scat_id": "0",
            "shop_prdt_code": "SKCT-28",
            "shop_prdt_title": "Pure Silk Cotton",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "150",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "120",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "30",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "30",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "35",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "25",
            "shop_prdt_size": "",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;fbPhotosPhotoCaption&quot; data-ft=&quot;{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:45,&amp;quot;tn&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;*G&amp;quot;}&quot; id=&quot;fbPhotoSnowliftCaption&quot; tabindex=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;hasCaption&quot;&gt;Women and pink ? Perfect combination ! Beautiful bright pink with vibrant coloured threadwork design on it, for a truly classy feel. For the woman who quietly walks into the room and takes everyone&amp;#39;s breath away&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &amp;quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&amp;quot;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "Pure Silk Cotton",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "For the woman who quietly walks into the room and takes everyone&#039;s breath away.",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Pure Silk Cotton, Cotton, Sharani Designs",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "13",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-09 22:15:05",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "7",
            "shop_cat_id": "1",
            "shop_scat_id": "3",
            "shop_prdt_code": "PTD-08GR",
            "shop_prdt_title": "House Wears with simple colors",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "15",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "13.90",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "1.1",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "25",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "11",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "3,8,10",
            "shop_prdt_size": "1,2,3,5,7,9,11",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&amp;#39;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don&amp;#39;t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&amp;#39;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &amp;quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&amp;quot;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "House Wears with simple colors",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Sharani Designs",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "39",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-09 21:48:51",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "2013-11-16 23:58:07",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

### LOGCAT:

```
  02-05 05:11:37.413: D/dalvikvm(2110): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 217K, 9% free 2968K/3260K, paused 26ms, total 28ms
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 8276 of {
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):    "Product":[
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):    {
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_id":"11",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_cat_id":"3",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_scat_id":"0",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_code":"06PTPL-01PK",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_title":"Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_listprice":"44",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_ourprice":"40",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_yousave":"4",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_stock":"20",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_weight":"17.67",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_weight_measurement":"GRM",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_color":"3,4,7,8,12,13,14",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_size":"3,5,11,13",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_spl_description":"",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_description":"&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales at. Nulla tellus elit, varius non commodo eget, mattis vel eros. In sed ornare nulla.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales at. Nulla tellus elit, varius non commodo eget, mattis vel eros. In sed ornare nulla.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_featured":"1",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_seo_title":"Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_seo_desc":"Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_seo_keywords":"Anarkkali Suits",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_images":"1",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_clicks":"13",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_createdon":"2013-10-29 02:26:08",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_updatedon":"2013-11-17 17:27:37",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_status":"1"
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):    },
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):    {
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_id":"10",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_cat_id":"4",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_scat_id":"0",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_code":"LEGG-GR01",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_title":"Premium Cotton Leggins",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_listprice":"15",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_ourprice":"13.90",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_yousave":"1.1",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_stock":"75",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_weight":"11",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_weight_measurement":"GRM",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_color":"9,12,23,26,27,28,29,36",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_size":"",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_spl_description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;fbPhotosPhotoCaption&quot; data-ft=&quot;{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:45,&amp;quot;tn&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;*G&amp;quot;}&quot; id=&quot;fbPhotoSnowliftCaption&quot; tabindex=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;hasCaption&quot;&gt;SLIGHT COLOUR VARIATIONS POSSIBLE DUE TO PHOTOGRAPHIC LIMITATIONS.&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_description":"&lt;p&gt;Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &amp;quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&amp;quot;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_featured":"1",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_seo_title":"Premium Cotton Leggins",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_seo_desc":"96% Premium Cotton and 4% Spandex",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_seo_keywords":"Premium Cotton Leggins, cotton, sharani designs",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_images":"1",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_clicks":"84",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_createdon":"2013-10-09 22:23:56",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_updatedon":"",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_status":"1"
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):    },  
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):    {
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_id":"9",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_cat_id":"2",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_scat_id":"0",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_code":"SKCT-38",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_title":"Pure Silk Cotton",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_listprice":"195",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_ourprice":"150",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_yousave":"45",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_stock":"34",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_weight":"110",
02-05 05:11:37.533: E/JSON Parser(2110):        "shop_prdt_weight
02-05 05:11:37.543: D/AndroidRuntime(2110): Shutting down VM
02-05 05:11:37.543: W/dalvikvm(2110): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a4ab90)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110): Process: com.androidhive.jsonparsing, PID: 2110
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.jsonparsing/com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:73)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-05 05:11:37.573: E/AndroidRuntime(2110):     ... 11 more
02-05 05:11:39.853: I/Process(2110): Sending signal. PID: 2110 SIG: 9
02-05 05:35:06.173: D/AndroidRuntime(2165): Shutting down VM
02-05 05:35:06.173: W/dalvikvm(2165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a4ab90)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): Process: com.androidhive.jsonparsing, PID: 2165
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.jsonparsing/com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:69)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-05 05:35:06.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     ... 11 more
02-05 05:35:07.913: I/Process(2165): Sending signal. PID: 2165 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Yes, You have to post your logcat.

Comment: Check your JSON String not valid. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: point out exactly where in my code.. @PratikButani

Comment: yes i have defined, i added internet permission also. actully it was worked fine with other json file, but this file is something getting error.

Comment: The JSON is still invalid. `Parse error on line 49: ...op_prdt_images": "1""shop_prdt_clicks": `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON parsing error has been solved since i was parsed a wrong url with the invalid json,

Problem solved and project run successfully, Thanks for all your support with step by step correction.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your JSON file near

```
"shop_prdt_images": "1""shop_prdt_clicks": "13",
```

Should be

```
"shop_prdt_images": "1",
"shop_prdt_clicks": "13",
```

Comment: No, there is no error in tat line. see in my json file clearly. its clearly separated with "," @Manitoba

Comment: Thanks, But after i have edited my code with the "comma" the same problem arised.. @Manitoba

Comment: i validated and got a valid json, @ling.s still the problem is getting closed while deploy to emulator

Comment: The error might have changed. Please update your post.

Comment: Btw to avoid crash but keep handling the exception, move `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` into the `try/catch` brackets.

Comment: @Brendon what is in `AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java` at line 73?

Comment: Look at my above comment. This is that line. Which means the JSON is malformed.

Comment: The `Json` is not in correct format again. @Brendon you are not posting the original json, the json differs from the one you posted

Comment: Yes, due to the characted limit i deleted some of them, still its a valid one, the number of products i reduced, thats it.

Comment: Have you tested? post first three json arrays

Comment: @Brendon error is showing after `"shop_prdt_weight":"110",
 "shop_prdt_weight`. There might be two elements with the same name as `shop_prdt_weight`

Comment: its actually ' "shop_prdt_weight": "110",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM", there is no error in tat part. @ling.s

Comment: is it possible to store the json file in assets folder and point out the url object to file:///android_asset/file.json ? whether it s a valid one? @ling.s

Answer (score 0):

Change like this and And run may be it is use full.
this line is error `"shop_prdt_images": "1""shop_prdt_clicks": "13",` change to  `"shop_prdt_images": "shop_prdt_clicks",` only one String is required.

```
    {
    "Product": [
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "11",
            "shop_cat_id": "3",
            "shop_scat_id": "0",
            "shop_prdt_code": "06PTPL-01PK",
            "shop_prdt_title": "Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "44",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "40",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "4",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "20",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "17.67",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "3,4,7,8,12,13,14",
            "shop_prdt_size": "3,5,11,13",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales at. Nulla tellus elit, varius non commodo eget, mattis vel eros. In sed ornare nulla.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales at. Nulla tellus elit, varius non commodo eget, mattis vel eros. In sed ornare nulla.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "Party Wear Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Anarkkali Suits",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "13",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-29 02:26:08",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "2013-11-17 17:27:37",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "10",
            "shop_cat_id": "4",
            "shop_scat_id": "0",
            "shop_prdt_code": "LEGG-GR01",
            "shop_prdt_title": "Premium Cotton Leggins",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "15",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "13.90",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "1.1",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "75",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "11",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "9,12,23,26,27,28,29,36",
            "shop_prdt_size": "",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;fbPhotosPhotoCaption&quot; data-ft=&quot;{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:45,&amp;quot;tn&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;*G&amp;quot;}&quot; id=&quot;fbPhotoSnowliftCaption&quot; tabindex=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;hasCaption&quot;&gt;SLIGHT COLOUR VARIATIONS POSSIBLE DUE TO PHOTOGRAPHIC LIMITATIONS.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &amp;quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&amp;quot;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "Premium Cotton Leggins",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "96% Premium Cotton and 4% Spandex",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Premium Cotton Leggins, cotton, sharani designs",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "84",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-09 22:23:56",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "9",
            "shop_cat_id": "2",
            "shop_scat_id": "0",
            "shop_prdt_code": "SKCT-38",
            "shop_prdt_title": "Pure Silk Cotton",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "195",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "150",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "45",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "34",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "110",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "11,24,30",
            "shop_prdt_size": "",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;fbPhotosPhotoCaption&quot; data-ft=&quot;{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:45,&amp;quot;tn&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;*G&amp;quot;}&quot; id=&quot;fbPhotoSnowliftCaption&quot; tabindex=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;hasCaption&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;text_exposed_show&quot;&gt;We promise you, our camera has NOT done justice to the true beauty of this saree. Don&amp;#39;t miss it !&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;fbPhotosPhotoCaption&quot; data-ft=&quot;{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:45,&amp;quot;tn&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;*G&amp;quot;}&quot; id=&quot;fbPhotoSnowliftCaption&quot; tabindex=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;hasCaption&quot;&gt;Oh, where do we start ? Woven with the classic &amp;quot;diamond needle&amp;quot; technique (whereby the body of the saree has fine gold lines running vertically), this sweet purple piece has an overall shimmer that automatically translates to RICH AND CLASSY. What makes t&lt;span class=&quot;text_exposed_show&quot;&gt;his piece unique ? Well, for starters, this kind of pallu with huge &amp;quot;twin mango&amp;quot; motifs is not commonly found in Silk Cotton Sarees (or any other saree !). As a bonus, the twin mango design will run along the top as well as the bottom of the saree !&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "Pure Silk Cotton",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "Woven with the classic &quot;diamond needle&quot; technique",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Pure Silk Cotton, Cotton, Sharani Designs",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "34",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-09 22:20:43",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "8",
            "shop_cat_id": "2",
            "shop_scat_id": "0",
            "shop_prdt_code": "SKCT-28",
            "shop_prdt_title": "Pure Silk Cotton",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "150",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "120",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "30",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "30",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "35",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "25",
            "shop_prdt_size": "",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;fbPhotosPhotoCaption&quot; data-ft=&quot;{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:45,&amp;quot;tn&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;*G&amp;quot;}&quot; id=&quot;fbPhotoSnowliftCaption&quot; tabindex=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;hasCaption&quot;&gt;Women and pink ? Perfect combination ! Beautiful bright pink with vibrant coloured threadwork design on it, for a truly classy feel. For the woman who quietly walks into the room and takes everyone&amp;#39;s breath away&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &amp;quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&amp;quot;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "Pure Silk Cotton",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "For the woman who quietly walks into the room and takes everyone&#039;s breath away.",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Pure Silk Cotton, Cotton, Sharani Designs",
            "shop_prdt_images": "shop_prdt_clicks",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-09 22:15:05",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "shop_prdt_id": "7",
            "shop_cat_id": "1",
            "shop_scat_id": "3",
            "shop_prdt_code": "PTD-08GR",
            "shop_prdt_title": "House Wears with simple colors",
            "shop_prdt_listprice": "15",
            "shop_prdt_ourprice": "13.90",
            "shop_prdt_yousave": "1.1",
            "shop_prdt_stock": "25",
            "shop_prdt_weight": "11",
            "shop_prdt_weight_measurement": "GRM",
            "shop_prdt_color": "3,8,10",
            "shop_prdt_size": "1,2,3,5,7,9,11",
            "shop_prdt_spl_description": "&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&amp;#39;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_description": "&lt;p&gt;There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don&amp;#39;t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&amp;#39;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, &amp;quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..&amp;quot;, comes from a line in section 1.10.32.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;p&gt;The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from &amp;quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&amp;quot; by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
            "shop_prdt_featured": "1",
            "shop_prdt_seo_title": "House Wears with simple colors",
            "shop_prdt_seo_desc": "This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance",
            "shop_prdt_seo_keywords": "Sharani Designs",
            "shop_prdt_images": "1",
            "shop_prdt_clicks": "39",
            "shop_prdt_createdon": "2013-10-09 21:48:51",
            "shop_prdt_updatedon": "2013-11-16 23:58:07",
            "shop_prdt_status": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the json errors others have pointed out, you're doing a network request on the main thread - this is bad for user experience and will crash on ICS+ with a NetworkOperationOnUiThreadException (or something like that).

You need to do the network request on a background thread

Comment: But am a fresher in tat web service part, so i dont know to do in background threads.